# Clarification for maximizing the Rayleigh Quotient

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a Hermitian matrix $M$ with orthonormal eigenbasis $\{x_1, \ldots x_n \}$, then for a unit vector $v$, I am reading about maximizing the Rayleigh quotient $R(M,t) =\frac{t* M t}{t^*t}$ = $t^*Mt = \lambda_i t_i^2$, where $t_i$ is the $i'th$ co-ordinate of $t$ in the eigenbasis. The max value is stated in my notes to be obtained by choosing $y$ to be the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $M$.

It's clear to me that among the choices $x_i$ that $R(M,x_i)$ is maximal for $x_i$ corresponding to $\lambda_{max}$ since $M{x_i} = \lambda_{max}$, but I'm not sure why there couldn't be some other vector $y$ a combination of the eigenvectors that would give a larger output.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it might be easier to look at  $\max_{\|t\|^2 = 1} t^*Mt$ and use
Lagrange multipliers which will give (since the gradient of the constraint is always non zero and hence linearly independent)
$Mt - \mu t = 0$ at a maximiser and so $\mu$ must be an eigenvalue and $t$ must be a corresponding eigenvector.

Since the cost is continuous and the constraint set compact we know there is a maxmimiser. Since the cost
at a solution of $Mt - \mu t = 0$ is $\mu$ we see it is maximised when $\mu$
is as large as possible, hence the maximum eigenvalue.

I'm not sure if this was the point of confusion, but note that
$\ker (M-\mu I)$ may be more than one dimensional.